# Jquery mobile gridview dynamic creation

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm learning jquery mobile..I need to create gridview dynamically from json value..How can i do this..

***till now i tried..***

this is my gridview

```
 <div class="ui-grid-a" id="category_grid">
            <div id="category_gridrow" class="ui-block-b"><p>This is block A</p></div>              
 </div>
```

my script data....

```
 <script >

var data = { "Products":[
        {
            "itemname":"Camera",
            "submenu": [{
                "itemname":"cannon",
            },{
                "itemname":"Kodak",
            },{
                "itemname":"Sony",
            }]
        },

        {
            "itemname":"Lighting",
        },

        {
            "itemname":"Backdrop",
             "submenu": [{
                "itemname":"Blue",
            },{
                "itemname":"Black",
            }]
        }
]}  

var cat='';


 for (var i in data.Products)
  {          
            cat  ="<p>"+ data.Products[i].itemname + "</p>";        
           $("#category_gridrow").html(cat);         
 }
</script>
```

But i dont know how to increase the grid dynamically..help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well friends i found it.. we can add like below..

```
$('#category_grid').append('<div id="category_gridrow" class="ui-block-b">'+cat+'</div></div>');
```